# log4j "bridge" and the RootLogger class

Tags: log4j, log4j2

We're trying to force an old vendor-provided Java-program (a JAR) to use log4j2, with the help of the [log4j "bridge"](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.2/log4j-1.2-api/index.html).

To do this, I:

- Deleted all entries starting with `org/apache/log4j/*` from the vendor's JAR
- Added the [`log4j-1.2-api-2.17.1.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-1.2-api/2.17.1) and the regular `log4j-*-2.17.1.jar` files to CLASSPATH

The program dies unable to find the `org/apache/log4j/spi/RootLogger`. Listing the contents of the bridge JAR, I find several classes under the `org/apache/log4j/spi/`, but the `RootLogger` is, indeed, missing.

How do I deal with this?

Comment: Version `2.17.2` will contain the `RootLogger` class. Can you try with it? It's available from [Apache's staging repository](https://repository.apache.org/#view-repositories).

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz, thank you. Using 2.17.2 helped. Care to turn your comment into a proper answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newest version 2.17.2 of Log4j2 contains a couple of dozen of fixes to the Log4j 1.x bridge (cf. [changelog](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/changes-report.html#a2.17.2)).

Among them the `org.apache.log4j.RootLogger` class has been added to provide binary compatibility with Log4j 1.x.

Warning: many of the added classes are no-ops and just prevent `ClassNotFoundException`s as the one in your question.